# how to access custom C typedefs, enums from unity C#?

Tags: c#, c, unity-game-engine

I am learning to write C plugins for Unity.

From C# I can access functions declared in my C code using dllImport. But now I would like to also access typedef enums etc declared in its .h file.

For instance in my C .h file I have something like:

```
typedef struct _myStruct  * myStruct_handle_t;
```

and

```
void          myCFunction(  myStruct_handle_t myStruct );
```

now when i try importing this function in C# script with dllImport, I get the following error:

Assets/PluginImport.cs(28,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `myStruct_handle_t' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

How can I use types defined in my C code? For instance is there a way to include my .h file in my c# script?

thanks,

Baba

Comment: It's just a wild guess, but: You could try to create a C# struct with exactly the same members (type and member-order) and try to use that C# struct as parameter in your DllImport-annotated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in my case the type i wanted to use was an opaque pointer. Therefore I actually did not need (want) to expose the internals of my struct to the c# script. In that case the solution is to simply write IntPtr instead of myStruct_handle_t in my dllImport extern declaration and it works.

For the enum I just redefined them as public enum myEnum_t : int { /* .. enums, */} in my C# script